# What's the problem with a new tag 'title'?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think it could be a fun and useful tag. See That Japanese Man Yuta's video: [What Japanese Anime Titles Mean](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHvvkUATHFs)

See my posts / edit suggestions.

https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70976

https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70975

https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70974

https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70973

https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/70972

[Bloody Monday - Is it still Bloody Monday?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67689/bloody-monday-is-it-still-bloody-monday)

[Sword Art Online - Is it still SAO?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67690/sword-art-online-is-it-still-sao)

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend you take a look at the Help center article [What are tags, and how should I use them](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/tagging), specifically the *Avoid meta-tags* part of it.

The suggested title tag does not add anything to the questions.

It's also strongly suggested to discussing the introduction of potential new tags as such on the meta first. If you unsure how to do so, you can take a look at the [many tag suggestions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdiscussion%5D+%5Btags%5D+do+we+need) that have already been posted prior